# Disable Logging test results at Cypress

Tags: cypress

I run my tests in the docker container and I would not want to see the logs about the results of the tests (since I run several instances of cypress and logs are mixed). Is there any way to turn off logging?

I have read documentation but i haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

As per this github issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2071.
That issue was resolved at the 4.9.0 release of Cypress.
You can now run your Cypress tests with the `--quiet` flag. e g.:

```
cypress run --quiet
```